# "Getting Started" Sencha ExtJs WebComponents with VueJS does not work

Tags: vue.js, extjs

I'm trying to follow the ["Getting Started with Vue"](https://docs.sencha.com/extwebcomponents/7.5.0/guides/getting_started/getting_started_vue.html) tutorial for Sencha web components but got an issue related to the initialization of the Google Maps script. What is strange because according to the tutorial I need only a panel component.
Here is the screenshot of the error:
[image]

Does someone know how to disable map initialization if I'm not going to use it?